# Can't get optional route param on the correct route segment

Tags: angular, angular-routing

```
path: 'dealers',
component: DealersComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'deals-stats',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':vendorId',
```

Trying to do `this.router.navigate(['.', {startDate: date}]);` from `/dealers/deals-stats/1934`. It's putting the `startDate` after `dealers` and not after `1934` like I want it to.

Pretty sure this has to do with the first element of the array on navigate. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `this.router.url + &startDate=date`

Comment: specify what this route is relative to with something like `{relativeTo: this.route}` assuming `this.route` is injected as ActivatedRoute.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, I see where you're going with that. `this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url + ';startDate=' + date);` worked, but I really don't like that.

Comment: @dmcgrandle that worked.  Thanks both.

Comment: @dmcgrandle that was a nice answer

Comment: @madhavsaibhushan thx.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode  date  before route navigate 
It works

Comment: The date is a string, but also, I saw that it does encode dates automatically.  Too much info, though.